# Partial render AJAX, c#, Asp.Net, visual web part

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ascx:

```
<div id="temasatratar" onclick="__doPostBack('fakeButton', '');"><h1>Temas a tratar</h1></div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="fakeButton" style="display:none" runat="server" Text="foo" OnClick="fakeButton_Click" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" onload="UpdatePanel1_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="fakeButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Behind code:

```
    protected void fakeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }

    protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int x = ran.Next(9999);
        Label1.Text = x.ToString();
    }
```

The problem: the code recharge completely the page and no the UploadPanel1.
How recharge only the UploadPanel1?

Any suggest?

My app: C# / Visual web Part / Asp.Net / Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="temasatratar"><h1>Temas a tratar</h1></div>
<asp:Button ID="fakeButton" style="display:none" runat="server" Text="foo" OnClick="fakeButton_Click"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" onload="UpdatePanel1_Load" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="fakeButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $('#temasatratar').click(function () {
            console.log('clicked');
            $('#<%= fakeButton.ClientID %>').click();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: :O wow! thanks a lot! your answer is correct. I wonder if do you can tell me why?

Comment: you can invoke click event on Button by jquery, exactly as you would click it. Were previously you did '__doPostBack('fakeButton', '');' which invoked full postback

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I believe you are missing the scriptmanager control.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: The masterpage have this tag: `<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />`

Comment: I think you answer is wrong, Becouse if you are missing this tag when you start the web aplication the page will crash. And the problem that @Darkering has, Is that the update panel does not work correctly.

Comment: Yes, the answer is wrong; @Freak_Droid , why is the UpdatePanel wrong?